# refer to an element of JSON (Javascript) object

Tags: javascript, json, arrays, element

How do I refer to an element of JSON (Javascript) object.
exampe: alert(homes.Agents[1].name);

```
<script>
    var homes = [
 {
    "Agents" : {
        "name" : "Bob Barker",
        "name" : "Mona Mayflower" 
    },
    "Listings" : [
        {
            "h_id": "3",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "TX",
            "zip": "75201",
            "price": "162500" 
        },
        {
            "h_id": "4",
            "city": "Bevery Hills",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": "90210",
            "price": "319250" 
        },
        {
            "h_id": "5",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "00010",
            "price": "962500" 
        } 
    ]
}

];

</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

That's not exactly very good JSON above there, in the case of the Agents value the second key will override the first.

You probably meant:

```
 "Agents" : [
     {"name" : "Bob Barker"},
     {"name" : "Mona Mayflower"} 
 ],
```

Then you'd access the first agent's name as

```
homes[0]['Agents'][0]['Name']
```

Similarly, to get one of the values from the Listings, you'd do something akin to:

```
homes[0]['Listings'][0]['city']
- or -
homes[0].Listings[0].city
```

The dot syntax can be used wherever there is a valid identifier, else you need to use the array syntax.

As a side note, I'm not sure the structure of the data, but it's possible that you can eliminate the outer-level `[]` that's enclosing your whole structure in an array. Then you wouldn't need to access everything as `homes[0]['Listings']` and instead simply `homes['Listings']`.

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON syntax is wrong. You can't have the same key twice in an object. Instead, you need an array:

```
var homes = {
  "Agents" : [
    { "name" : "Bob Barker" },
    { "name" : "Mona Mayflower" }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Then you can access the agents like so:

```
homes.Agents[1] // => { "name": "Mona Mayflower" }

// or

homes.Agents[1].name // => "Mona Mayflower"
```

Comment: Your correction is invalid syntax, there needs to be a mapping ( `{ }` ) to use arbitrary keys. Namely, it'd fail on the line `"Agents" : [` because you're currently defining an array, not a mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Homes is an Array, so your first accessor is index based.

homes[0]

Agents is an Object, and Object containing two keys of the same name.  That is a no-no.

If you are defining this data yourself, you should change

```
"Agents": {
    "name" : "Bob Barker",
    "name" : "Mona Mayflower"
}
```

to

```
 "Agents": [
        {"name" : "Bob Barker"},
        {"name" : "Mona Mayflower"}
    ]
```

Then you could access the data in question by

```
homes[0].Agents[1].name
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give your object properties unique names. In your example, the second name property is overwriting the first so that homes[0].Agents.name will always be "Mona Mayflower".

Once you get that sorted, I think you're looking for this:

```
homes[0].Agents.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid JSON Agents is just an object, not an array.  If it was restructured like this:

```
"Agents" : [
  { "name" : "Bob Barker"},
  { "name" : "Mona Mayflower"}]
```

Then you could use `homes.Agents[1].name` to get 'Mona Mayflower'

Answer (score 0):

Example taken from the following [link](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

"`myJSONObject.bindings[0].method`" will return "`newURI`"