# sorting complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Refering to earlier questions about referencing elements of and sorting a JSON (javascript) array. See
[refer to an element of JSON (Javascript) object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074908/refer-to-an-element-of-json-javascript-object) 
[Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-a-json-array)

Is it possible to sort one branch of a more complex javascript array, such as sorting by price in the example below?

```
var homes = 
{
    "Agents" : [
        {
            "name" : "Bob Barker" 
        },
        {
            "name" : "Mona Mayflower" 
        } 
    ] ,
    "Listings" : [
        {
            "h_id": "3",
            "city": "Dallas",
            "state": "TX",
            "zip": "75201",
            "price": "162500" 
        },
        {
            "h_id": "4",
            "city": "Bevery Hills",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": "90210",
            "price": "319250" 
        },
        {
            "h_id": "5",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "00010",
            "price": "962500" 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

thanks you all your help!!!

**EDIT**

Sorry for the confusion. I meant Javascript as tag. (This should have been apparent by rest of question) I got the sort working, just having trouble iterating through the array.

```
// before sort 
alert(homes.Listings[0].price); 
// sort 
homes.Listings.sort(sort_by('price', false, parseInt));  
// after sort works: 
alert(homes.Listings[0].price); 
// iteration does not work "$ is not defined" 
$.each(homes.Listings, function(i, thisHome) { 
    alert(thisHome.price);  
});
```

Comment: @BalusC, that's what I was wondering and why I was apprehensive about posting my answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 5):

The standard `Array.sort` takes a comparator function. Use that:

```
function makeNumericCmp(property) {
    return function (a, b) {
        return parseInt(a[property]) - parseInt(b[property]);
    };
}
homes.Listings.sort(makeNumericCmp('price'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is more-or-less in the question you posted a link to:

[Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-a-json-array)

```
homes.Listings.sort(function (a, b)
{
    return a.price - b.price;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a toolkit, for example jQuery. See [Sorting JSON by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881510/json-sorting-question)

Comment: Why the down vote? Explaining your down vote seems like a decent thing to do.

Comment: I did not vote you down, but I suggest you are recommend a big hammer for a small problem.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know about "The standard Array.sort takes a comparator function."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. I meant Javascript as tag.
(This should have been apparent by rest of question)
I got the sort working, just having trouble iterating 
through the array.

```
// before sort
alert(homes.Listings[0].price);
// sort
homes.Listings.sort(sort_by('price', false, parseInt)); 
// after sort works:
alert(homes.Listings[0].price);
// iteration does not work "$ is not defined"
$.each(homes.Listings, function(i, thisHome) {
    alert(thisHome.price); 
});
```

Comment: This post is fine if intended as an answer to your question (which you're allowed to do), but otherwise you should edit your question to add clarifications. SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. As for the error, it's because `$` isn't a standard object; it's defined by various libraries, which you probably didn't load.

Comment: I've added this updated information to your question - please delete this "answer".

Comment: Thanks for kind advice. JS library fell off the page during edit.
I didn't even think of checking that.